# How to map an association table that carries some attributes

Tags: xml, hibernate, mapping

im using hibernate xml to map my databse, but i didn't knew how to map a many to many  relation (STUDENT,COURSE,TEACHER) that have an association table(Student_Course_Teacher) ,this table carries the primary keys of the other tables, and also some other attributs such Date_Creation.
can some one tell me how it can be mapped using Hibernate xml.

My sincere regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-1.html) should help you

Comment: yeah i know that exemple, but my association table carry an attribute Date_Creation in addition of the primary keys of the other tables, so how should i map the association table? should i do like on the exemple there? or map the association table on it's own (Student_Course_Teacher.hbm.xml, Student_Course_Teacher.java)?

Comment: from what i read i think it will be better to devide the many-to-many relation ship, to many-to-one relations... and map the Student_Course_Teacher on it's own